# How to add UITextView to custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, swift5

Requirement: I want to add a row to UITableView whenever I type in the UITextView of UITableViewHeaderFooterView and click on the send button. UITableViewHeaderFooterView must be a reusable class.

I am not able to figure out where to add the UITextViewDelegate method(Whether in the custom class itself or in the main class where I use it.)

I followed [this](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/add-headers-and-footers-to-tableview-sections/) tutorial to create a custom footer class.

Logic for textViewDidChange

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - (sendButtonWidthConstraint.constant + textViewLeadingConstraint.constant), height: .infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)

        if estimatedSize.height >= self.textViewMaxHeight
        {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            textViewHeightConstraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
            containerViewHeightConstraint.constant = textViewHeightConstraint.constant + textViewBottomConstraint.constant + textViewTopConstraint.constant
            sendButtonBottomConstraint.constant = (containerViewHeightConstraint.constant - sendButtonHeightConstraint.constant)/2
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

PS: Basically, I am trying to develop the comments feature of Instagram.

Comment: You can set any of them as UITextViewDelegate. Set the one where you find it easy to manage.

Comment: I think you need to set the ViewController as UITextView delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UITableViewCell` as a Header or Footer view for reuse. Implement `TextViewDelegate` in it then send back to your `ViewController`.